# How to send SNMP v2 trap using Ararat Synapse?‏

Tags: delphi, snmp, lazarus

I've tried to modify the TrapSend.dpr sample project which I downloaded from http://synapse.ararat.cz/files/contrib/Trap.zip to send SNMP v2 traps without success. Note: I'm able to successfully send SNMP v1 traps using the sample.

This is the original function SendTrap in SNMPTrap.pas:

```
function SendTrap(Dest, Source, Enterprise, Community: string;
  Generic, Specific, Seconds: integer; MIBName, MIBValue: string; MIBtype:integer): integer;
var
  SNMP: TTrapSNMP;
begin
  SNMP := TTrapSNMP.Create;
  try
    SNMP.SNMPHost := Dest;
    SNMP.Trap.TrapHost := Source;
    SNMP.Trap.Enterprise := Enterprise;
    SNMP.Trap.Community := Community;
    SNMP.Trap.GenTrap := Generic;
    SNMP.Trap.SpecTrap := Specific;
    SNMP.Trap.TimeTicks := Seconds;
    SNMP.Trap.MIBAdd(MIBName,MIBValue,MIBType);
    Result := SNMP.Send;
  finally
    SNMP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

After reading the example in http://en.it-usenet.org/thread/14303/3313/, I modified SNMPTrap.pas to the following to send a generic linkdown SNMP v2 trap but it didn't work:

```
function SendTrap(Dest, Source, Enterprise, Community: string;
  Generic, Specific, Seconds: integer; MIBName, MIBValue: string; MIBtype:integer): integer;
var
  SNMP: TTrapSNMP;
begin
  SNMP := TTrapSNMP.Create;
  try
    SNMP.SNMPHost := Dest;
  //  SNMP.Trap.TrapHost := Source;
  //  SNMP.Trap.Enterprise := Enterprise;
    SNMP.Trap.Community := Community;
  //  SNMP.Trap.GenTrap := Generic;
  //  SNMP.Trap.SpecTrap := Specific;
   // SNMP.Trap.TimeTicks := Seconds;

  SNMP.Trap.Version := SNMP_V2C;
  SNMP.Trap.PDUType := PDUTrapV2;

   // SNMP.Trap.MIBAdd(MIBName,MIBValue,MIBType);
    SNMP.Trap.MIBAdd('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0','0',ASN1_TIMETICKS);
    SNMP.Trap.MIBAdd('1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0','1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3',ASN1_OBJID);
    Result := SNMP.Send;
  finally
    SNMP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Wireshark returned the following error:

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  50494 2016.821366000 192.168.0.125         192.168.0.10          SNMP     117    snmpV2-trap

Frame 50494: 117 bytes on wire (936 bits), 117 bytes captured (936 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_0b:d9:b8 (00:24:d7:0b:d9:b8), Dst: Hewlett-_48:5c:54 (00:23:7d:48:5c:54)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.125 (192.168.0.125), Dst: 192.168.0.10 (192.168.0.10)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 63309 (63309), Dst Port: snmptrap (162)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: snmpV2-trap (7)
        snmpV2-trap
            BER Error: Wrong field in sequence  expected class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:2(INTEGER) but found class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:6
                [Expert Info (Warn/Malformed): BER Error: Wrong field in sequence]
                    [Message: BER Error: Wrong field in sequence]
                    [Severity level: Warn]
                    [Group: Malformed]
            BER Error: Wrong field in sequence  expected class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:2(INTEGER) but found class:APPLICATION(1) tag:0
                [Expert Info (Warn/Malformed): BER Error: Wrong field in sequence]
                    [Message: BER Error: Wrong field in sequence]
                    [Severity level: Warn]
                    [Group: Malformed]
            error-index: 0
            BER Error: Wrong field in sequence  expected class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:16(SEQUENCE) but found class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:2
                [Expert Info (Warn/Malformed): BER Error: Wrong field in sequence]
                    [Message: BER Error: Wrong field in sequence]
                    [Severity level: Warn]
                    [Group: Malformed]
            BER Error: This field lies beyond the end of the known sequence definition.
                [Expert Info (Warn/Malformed): BER Error: Unknown field in Sequence]
                    [Message: BER Error: Unknown field in Sequence]
                    [Severity level: Warn]
                    [Group: Malformed]
            BER Error: This field lies beyond the end of the known sequence definition.
                [Expert Info (Warn/Malformed): BER Error: Unknown field in Sequence]
                    [Message: BER Error: Unknown field in Sequence]
                    [Severity level: Warn]
                    [Group: Malformed]
```

For comparison, I've included a correctly formed v2 SNMP trap (which I sent using ireasoning's trap sender).

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     54 7.697996000    192.168.0.125         192.168.0.10          SNMP     111    snmpV2-trap SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0

Frame 54: 111 bytes on wire (888 bits), 111 bytes captured (888 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_0b:d9:b8 (00:24:d7:0b:d9:b8), Dst: Hewlett-_48:5c:54 (00:23:7d:48:5c:54)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.125 (192.168.0.125), Dst: 192.168.0.10 (192.168.0.10)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 53423 (53423), Dst Port: snmptrap (162)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: snmpV2-trap (7)
        snmpV2-trap
            request-id: 75820535
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 2 items
                SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0): 0
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 (SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0)
                    Value (Timeticks): 0
                SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 (1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0): 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 (IF-MIB::linkDown)
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 (SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0)
                    Value (OID): 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 (IF-MIB::linkDown)
```

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm seeing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  There appears to be no way to send snmpv2 traps using delphi code.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the library you're using. I don't see anything wrong conceptually with your code (though I'm not a delphi programmer).

Comment: Probably so, but I'm not able to get a response from the author.